# What does magento flush cache storage deletes that affects product objects

Tags: php, magento

I'm encountering an error when I delete cache by flush cache storage. the issue when I add product to cart it causes Call to a member function on a non-object.  I checked the product object data and seems methods are missing .

The product type is bundle, and I'm adding to cart using custom code.  the missing methods are from the bundled products not the main one.

Comment: Any entry in logs? Any custom module which deals with cart/checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think so that removing cache woould have such side effect, I recommend you to disable cache and debug it.

Comment: It's not cache. it is flush cache storage.  I disabled cache, it works the same. it only happens if I click flush cache storage right before clicking add to cart. whether cache enabled or disabled

Comment: Ok, I discovered the issue.  it is a bug in the custom code that happens when I clear the cache. thanks